# How does SqlCommand.ExecuteReader() work?

Tags: c#, sql

After executing the sqlText that returns >10 million rows, my incoming bandwidth shoots up, but my process memory stays consistent. I am certain that the incoming bandwidth is coming from this process. This doesn't make sense to me since executeReader should only store one row in the reader object. I would think calling reader.read() would actually retrieve the data. Why does my incoming bandwidth shoot up?

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandTimeout = 0;
            command.CommandText = sqlText;
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you say it "shoots up", what exactly does that mean? How big is the increase? Bytes? MBs?

Comment: How are you measuring incoming bandwidth?

Comment: Look at your title, i guess you meant `ExecuteReader` not `ExecuteQuery`

Comment: I was shooting up to ~25Mbps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why it doesn't show up in your process memory I cannot answer. But basically, once the query has started producing results, the server sends them to the client as fast as it can<sup>1,2</sup>. Various levels of buffering may be involved and some of these (e.g. buffers inside the network drivers) will not be directly accounted for within your process.

As soon as possible, once all the results are delivered, the server can free up the resources that were required for your query and start using them to satisfy other queries (for other clients).

Having only a single result stored on the client and requiring every call to `Read` to pull a new row from the server requiring a network round trip each time would be *spectacularly* inefficient.

---

<sup>1</sup>Subject to whatever limitations are imposed by e.g. TCP windows.

<sup>2</sup>Often referred to as "firehose mode", as opposed to if you explicitly create a cursor for your query in which you do control the rate of retrieval from the server.